# IOS: UIButton from UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to assign a result of swiping to a button, so I can proceed with further actions.
I found a straightforward way of doing it, but unfortunately not very elegant and throwing a warning.

Example: assume *recognizer* is an instance of *UISwipeGestureRecognizer*.
Then...

```
UIButton *buttonHit = [recognizer view];
```

It works, but results in

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UIButton *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'
```

Any better way of achieving the same? I didn't find any UIButton special constructor. I must be missing something simple. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can cast the UIView to UIButton, it will remove the warning: `UIButton *buttonHit = (UIButton*)[recognizer view]`. Seems reasonable if you are sure the `recognizer.view` is and will always be the UIButton you are expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton * buttonHit = (UIButton *)[recognizer view];
NSAssert([buttonHit isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]], @"Recognizer must be associated with a UIButton");
```

Comment: All right. Thanks for the extra line to make sure button is a button ;)